# Why dropdown list items do not show at my simple_form_for collection code when I render the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, simple-form

I am trying to insert a simple_form drop down list in my page but I am having troubles with showing the list items (Two email addresses - conatct@test.com and support@test.com). When I click the drop down list arrow they simply do not show as they were not there.

```
.reveal.doubt id="doubt-material-#{material.id}" data-reveal=true
  button.close-button data-close=true aria-label="Close reveal" type="button"
    span aria-hidden="true" &times;
  h5 #{t 'students.materials.index.questions.button'}
  p #{t 'students.materials.index.questions.form_explanation'}
  = simple_form_for [:student, trail, component, material, material_student, doubt], html: { id: "doubt" }, remote: true do |f|
    = f.input :recipient, collection => %w(contact@test.com, support@test.com), label: "#{t 'students.materials.index.questions.form_send_email'}"
    = f.input :question, as: :text, label: true, label: "#{t 'students.materials.index.questions.form_message'}" , input_html: { rows: "2" }
    = f.submit "#{t 'students.materials.index.questions.form_send_button'}", class: 'button primary-button-active'
```

When I inspect the code it seems it is working but I can not see the email options anywhere.

The code line I have added is:

`= f.input :recipient, collection: %w(contact@test.com, support@test.com), label: "#{t 'students.materials.index.questions.form_send_email'}"`

What is wrong here ?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the label? It looks like you might get what you want with out it. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections
Try the following see if it helps 
= f.input :recipient, collection => %w(contact@test.com, support@test.com)

Comment: Does not work either. Have already tried that and saw the documentation. I have notice that Select2 is "instaled" in the app. Do you think it migth be tha problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your collection needs the `name` and `value` to be set for each option. You could try: `[["contact@test.com", "contact@test.com"], ["support@test.com", "support@test.com"]]`. Or use the Rails [options_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) helper method:

```rb
= f.input :recipient, collection => options_for_select(%w[contact@test.com contact@test.com])
```

Comment: Thanks but none of them worked for me. I have already tried the first suggestion with no success.